# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Philosophy breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         13
Users destroyed                                  19          0
Users deleted                                     6          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            38        782
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               24        363
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          9        603
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3        430
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0      1,823
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               61      3,014
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          1
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                                8          4
Questions protected                              38         17
Questions migrated                                5          1
Questions flagged⁴                                3        406
Questions closed                                232        340
Question flags handled⁴                         241        168
Posts unlocked                                    1          7
Posts undeleted                                  16         93
Posts locked                                      8         29
Posts deleted⁵                                  590        911
Posts bumped                                      0        969
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               43          0
Comments flagged                                 17        634
Comments deleted⁶                             3,380      3,431
Comment flags handled                           340        311
Answers flagged                                  17        822
Answer flags handled                            731        108
All comments on a post moved to chat            105          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...