# For Reference (and discussion if you want): Comparison 2019-2020 Review Queues

Tags: discussion, moderation

After seeing [2020 Year in Moderation](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/2020-a-year-in-moderation?cb=1) I've taken the liberty of comparing it to last year's [Review](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/2019-a-year-in-moderation). Specifically, what draws my attention was the comparison of the Review Queues.

Thought if I was interested, perhaps others might as well, so I've made a quick comparison for the users (you may share your opinions in the comments/answers, but I've mainly done it for reference in the future).

| Task | Mods+Community - 2019 | Mods+Community - 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tasks reviewed: Suggested Edit queue | 878 | 809 |
| Tasks reviewed: Reopen Vote queue | 571 | 256 |
| Tasks reviewed: Low Quality Posts queue | 502 | 243 |
| Tasks reviewed: Late Answer queue | 377 | 342 |
| Tasks reviewed: First Post queue | 1,589 | 1,311 |
| Tasks reviewed: Close Votes queue | 4,809 | 3,160 |

---

If I may share, my personal opinion is that we can obviously see a decline in reviews (some queues suffered more, like Reopen and Low Quality which may be discussed further). I would like to be hopeful and say that we can see a welcomed decline in Close Votes, but the fact that we don't see a bump in a different queue (for example Suggested Edit, which should be stated that has suffered almost the least since last year) shows that it might just be a part of general decline in reviews, and not a sudden change in the way the users review (one we've talked a lot about).

Comment: We don't have a `reference` tag so I couldn't think of a better one than those. Changes in tags are welcomed.